# schüsselweise meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Müller Lümmer frühstückt **schüsselweise** grünes Gemüse.

What does the bold word within the tongue twister mean? I cannot find the meaning in any dictionary.

Comment: Seems to be a sentence containing as many _ü_'s as possible. That is to say: One should not worry too much about the meaning of the sentence, it is a 'Sprachspiel'.

Comment: ein Zungenbrecher, besser gesagt @RalfJoerres

Comment: Für mich sind Zungenbrecher schwer auszusprechende Sätze oder Phrasen (Brautkleid bleibt Brautkleid und Blaukraut bleibt Blaukraut.) Aber viele Deutschlerner haben überhaupt Probleme mit dem 'ü', so gesehen ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that he eats large portions of vegetable. A "Schüssel" is a bowl, bigger than an ordinary dish. I do not think one should take it in the literal sense that he actually fills some bowls and eats the vegetable contained in them, but we should understand it in the sense of "very much".

The ending *weise* occurs also in "massenweise" which could be alternatively be used:

> Müller Lümmer frühstückt massenweise grünes Gemüse.

See also [here](https://germanblogs.de/schreibweise-so-schreibt-man-seltsamerweise-woerter-mit-der-endung-weise/).

Comment: You might translate this as "bowls of", or "by the bowl", or even "bowls and bowls of"; some unspecified amount but at least several bowls full, though one would expect a certain amount of hyperbole in a statement like this.

Answer (score 8):

It's a combination of the suffix *-weise*, which can be used to form an indication of quantity, and *Schüssel*, which simply means bowl.

So literally *schüsselweise* means he eats some number of bowls of green vegetables.

In a recipe, for example, you might read *man gebe das Mehl löffelweise hinzu*, meaning *add the flour spoon by spoon*.

In another variation there is *zent­ner­wei­se*, which simply means a lot, and comes from *Zentner*, an old unit of weight.

Comment: I'd say *-weise* is manner, not quantity (the noun specifies the quantity).

Comment: @DavidVogt That might be a good literal translation, but I was speaking about its use. See Duden, for example, which also says "wird mit Substantiven zur Bildung von Adverbien verwendet, die dann eine Maß- oder Mengeneinheit ausdrücken".

Comment: Actually, I misspoke. The noun itself does not express a quantity, but a unit of measurement. I wonder how the adverb can also be a unit of measurement? What does *-weise* add, if not manner (as indicated by the paraphrase given by Duden *in, Schüsseln, nach Schüsseln*).

Comment: @DavidVogt: I don't agree: unit of measurement is tightly coupled to concerned quantity, otherwise one would use a different unit. This is even more so for a unit specifically invented for a sentence. So *eimerweise* suggests, that we are talking about a (unspecified) multiple of 10 litres and not about 0.4 l e. g. of milk to be added to a cake.